# Is there a way in Numbers to flip columns with rows?

Tags: numbers

Is there a way in Numbers to flip columns with rows ?

I have several tables in my sheet and I need to swap columns with rows for each table.

e.g.

```
A1  A2  A3
B1  B2  B3
C1  C2  C3
```

should become:

```
A1  B1  C1
A2  B2  C2
A3  B3  C3
```

thanks

Comment: This is called 'transpose'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a one-year old [question](https://superuser.com/q/133994) in Super User about this.
It links to an [Apple forum page](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8799221?messageID=8799221) where you will be told to how to use INDEX and TRANSPOSE functions to achieve what you're looking for.
The Past Special of Excel is way easier but this function is not widely used so apparently dropped from Numbers.

Answer (score 37):

With the table selected, simply choose Table > Transpose Rows and Columns.

[image]

Comment: how do you select the table though?

Comment: @tubbo Click it.

Comment: Remark: Feature not available in Apple Numbers 2.x (from iWork '09 suite).